# Carbon date check if it is specified date

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

I have a link in my menu where I pass date to filter. But I want to achieve this:

- If date is weekday, I want to show day before. For example if it is Thursday, `2017-09-28`, I want to show Wednesday `2017-09-27`
- If date is weekend, I want to show last friday before weekend. For example if it is `2017-09-23` or `2017-09-24` I want to show `2017-09-22`
- If date is Monday, I want to show last friday. For example if date is `2017-09-25`, I want to show `2017-09-23`

For now I did this:

```
<li class="navMenu">
  <a href="/latest?date=
    @if (Carbon\Carbon::today()->isWeekday())

     {{Carbon\Carbon::yesterday()->format('Y-m-d')}}

    @else 
      {{Carbon\Carbon::now()->startOfWeek()->format('Y-m-d')}}
    @endif">{{ trans('language.newCampaigns') }}
   </a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fall back to native PHP [`->modify`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php) modifiers since Carbon inherits from date:

```
<li class="navMenu">
  <a href="/latest?date={{Carbon\Carbon::today()->modify("last weekday")->format('Y-m-d')}}">    
   </a>
</li>
```

Comment: Simple and awesome solution! :)